# How do I browse all the files uploaded to Moodle

Tags: moodle

Moodle stores references to all files uploaded to it in its database, the files themselves get hashed and stored on disk but you cannot work out what the files are by looking at them on the disk.

Is there somewhere in the Moodle interface that lets you browse all the files that have been uploaded as an admin?

Is this available as a plugin?  Looking for some kind of global file store browser.